# python replacing the column values with other file

Tags: python, pandas

#Importing pandas module

```
    import pandas as pd
```

#reading the files to merge/ or replace together

```
     file1 = pandas.read_excel ("file1 name.xlsx")

     file2 = pandas.read_excel ("file2 name.xlsx")
```

#1. indicate the column headers that I want to replace with ex) there are two columns "column1", "column2"

```
    columns_replace = ["column1", "column2"]
```

#2. need to delete the vlaues in columns that i want to replace

```
    file2.drop(columns_replace, axis = "columns", inplace= true)
```

#3. replacing the values that I want to overwrite

```
    file2[columns_replace] = file1[columns_replace]
```

Questions:
How to replace the values in the same column name in between two files?

I want file 2 has the same value as file 1 under the same column name.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please format your code properly.

Comment: Can you explain more? i am not sure what you mean, and i am pretty new to code in Python

Comment: Do these data frames share any columns? If so you can merge them instead. Maybe give an example of your desired input and output

Comment: Thanks! I want to replace the values in column file1 to the values in column file 2. how can i do that? Both files have the same column name and number of rows